# Webpack renames files in srcset with w descriptor

Tags: html, image, webpack, descriptor, srcset

Here is my source HTML code

```html
<picture aria-hidden="true">
    <source srcset="
        ./img/find/video-preview-318.webp 318w,
        ./img/find/video-preview-635.webp 635w,
        ./img/find/video-preview-866.webp 866w
    " 
    type="image/webp">

    <source srcset="
        ./img/find/video-preview-318.jpg 318w,
        ./img/find/video-preview-635.jpg 635w,
        ./img/find/video-preview-866.jpg 866w
    " 
    type="image/jpeg">
                    
    <img 
        class="video__poster" 
        sizes="(min-width: 1920px) 33vw, (min-width: 993px) 50vw, (min-width: 769px) 70vw, 100vw" 
        src="./img/find/video-preview-635.jpg" 
    alt="">
</picture>
```

After build, I get this

```html
<picture aria-hidden="true">
    <source srcset="
        assets/img/video-preview-318.webpw-318.webp 318w, 
        assets/img/video-preview-635.webpew-635.webp 635w, 
        assets/img/video-preview-866.webpiew-866.webp 866w" 
    type="image/webp">

    <source srcset="
        assets/img/video-preview-318.jpgew-318.jpg 318w, 
        assets/img/video-preview-635.jpgiew-635.jpg 635w, 
        assets/img/video-preview-866.jpgview-866.jpg 866w" 
    type="image/jpeg">
                    
    <img 
        class="video__poster" 
        sizes="(min-width: 1920px) 33vw, (min-width: 993px) 50vw, (min-width: 769px) 70vw, 100vw"
        src="./img/find/video-preview-635.jpg" 
    alt="">
</picture>
```

Why have the file names in srcset changed so much?

When I use the x descriptor, everything works if the files are named as follows

```html
<picture aria-hidden="true">
    <source srcset="
        ./img/hero/hero-bg.webp 1x, 
        ./img/hero/hero-bg@2x.webp 2x" 
    type="image/webp">

    <source srcset="
        ./img/hero/hero-bg.png 1x, 
        ./img/hero/hero-bg@2x.png 2x" 
    type="image/x-png">
                
    <img class="hero__bg hero__bg--image" src="./img/hero/hero-bg.png" alt="">
</picture>
```

How then should the files be named when using w descriptor?

I am using html-loader

```js
...

 rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    'html-loader',
                ]
            },

            ...

         ]

...
```

I need the file names to not change in srcset attribute using w descriptor after the webpack build